# Delayed Geolocator

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to follow the users location, this works fine for the first time executing. But when I do something else in the app and then try to start again tracking the user's location, then the processindicator is shown for a very long time and then this message appears:

```
I/art     ( 2803): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 308336(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 166(23MB) LOS objects, 26% free, 43MB/59MB, paused 2.902ms total 135.647ms
```

After this it works just fine.

(Does this mean I used too much memory and because of this the garbage collector took this long? And What do I have to change? Is there a problem with the streams? Or do I have to dispose something?)

This is my Geolocator class:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class GeolocatorService{


Stream<Position> getCurrentLocation(){

return Geolocator.getPositionStream(distanceFilter: 5,);

}

Future<Position> getInitialLocation() async{

  return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}
 
  }
```

This is the Map:

```
class MapAction extends StatefulWidget {
  MapAction({Key key, this.inputText})
      : super(key: key);
  final String inputText;

  @override
  MapActionState createState() => MapActionState();
}

class MapActionState extends State<MapAction> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Position>(
        stream: GeolocatorService().getCurrentLocation(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {

            return Center(
              child: Container(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            );
          } else {

            return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: GoogleMap(   
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(
                          snapshot.data.latitude, snapshot.data.longitude),
                      zoom: 15.0),
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  //mapType: MapType.satellite,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                ));
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)